# configuring oracle-ds.xml file in jboss

Tags: configuration, database, command-line-interface, oracle, jboss

how can I connect jboss with database and how can I configure `oracle-ds.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do only few things:

1. Go to directory `docs/examples/jca` (in JBoss) and there you can find `oracle-ds.xml` file, you can use that file as a template for your configuration.
2. Copy `oracle-ds.xml` to your profile directory (for example `default`).
3. Edit that file and set up your JDBC connection string.
4. Copy jar library with Oracle thin database drivers to profle `lib` directory.
5. Start your JBoss server.

You can find more information on that subject on JBoss Community Wiki: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/configdatasources.